# How to call reload after animation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a news feed style page that will automatically scroll to the bottom, then wait and refresh the page and repeat the process.

The automatic reload is not working at the moment, and it is starting to bug me.

any help is greatly appreciated.

The Scrolling part works great

My code currently

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function scrolll() {
    time = $('.message').length*3000;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, time,0, function() {location.reload; });
        ;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
location.reload();
```

or

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

but I think your problem with **time,0**

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, time, function() {location.reload(); });
```

and if I understood you can use `setTimeout()`

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 100, function() { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload();
        }, time)
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nfgv20b3/)

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing

```
location.reload;
```

to

```
location.reload(true);
```

(which will also avoid using the page cache on reload ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload))).

Next, consider the animate signature:

> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

In your animation you are passing `0` as the easing name

```
.animate({...}, time, 0, function() ...
```

which will prevent the animation from starting. Either omit this altogether, or pass in a valid easing name such as "linear". See [here](https://jqueryui.com/easing/) for easing function names if you are interested.